# #define __CLIBNS ::std:: in C standard header files such as stdio.h

Tags: c++, arm

I see the following definition in the standard header file `stdio.h` of the ARM compiler:

```
#undef __CLIBNS
#ifdef __cplusplus
  namespace std {
  #define __CLIBNS ::std::
    extern "C" {
#else /* ndef __cplusplus */
  #define __CLIBNS
#endif /* ndef __cplusplus */
```

What is the significance of this? What if I have to port the code which uses `_CLIBNS` in gcc?
Are there similar macros I should use?

Comment: `_CLIBNS` is a reserved identifier, so whoever wrote it screwed up (plus it wouldn't conflict anyway...)

Comment: this code is from the standard header file itself ie stdio.h, this defines __CLIBNS for armcc, i need to port a code which uses this macro to another compiler ie gcc, so i want to understand any equivalent compiler define is there in gcc

Answer (score 0):

`_CLIBNS` doesn't conflict. You might hit issues if you use `__CLIBNS` (two underscores) in your code, but you're already doing something you're not supposed to. Names with two leading underscores are reserved for the compiler.

Comment: As are names which begin with an underscore followed by a capital letter, so the OP has a non-issue on his hands.

Comment: this code is from the standard header file itself ie stdio.h, this defines __CLIBNS for armcc, i need to port a code which uses this macro to another compiler ie gcc, so i want to understand any equivalent compiler define is there in gcc

Comment: @Madhu If your code defines `__CLIBNS` then it's non-standard code. The proper fix is to refactor the code to not use a reserved name.

Answer (score 0):

The significance is that `<stdio.h>` very carefully uses a reserved identifier for internal purposes so it cannot clash with any of your code. Since it's for internal purposes, **your** code should not mention the macro at all. Thus this simplifies porting.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer:  you probably don't want to use armcc's copy of `<stdio.h>` with gcc -- use gcc's (or newlib's).

`<stdio.h>` is allowed to use `__CLIBNS` because it is part of the implementation; you, as the user, are not (unless the implementation's documentation tells you otherwise).  In C there are no namespaces so `__CLIBNS` is defined to nothing.  In C++ most of the contents of `<stdio.h>` are in the global namespace `std` -- but not preprocessor macros (`#define`s) because they don't care about namespaces (macros are evil but historically necessary).  So `<stdio.h>` uses `__CLIBNS` in it's macro definitions to make sure that the macros it has to define refer to the things in the `std` namespace when you are using C++.